# Loading Records into my Suitelet PDF (Netsuite, SuiteScript)

Tags: javascript, netsuite, record, suitescript

NetSuite newbie here. I'm currently working on a Suitelet that displays an Issue data in PDF format (I created the structure using SuiteScript 1.0). The PDF works well but I want to load the Issues List to display their primary information on a table. Does anyone knows how I can load the Issues List to display that data?

I haven't tried to load it, since I'm looking for information regarding starting this task. I want to be able to load the Issues List on my script to display primary information.

Comment: There are a couple of ways to load data for PDF rendering. Please show what you've done so far -- mainly are you using a template renderer or are you generating the pdf from one of the print transaction methods?